# Append html code to mxgraph diagrm befor export

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, mxgraph

I am not an English native speaker so please ignore my grammar mistakes.

The question is,

**I am drawing shapes on the div using mxgraph and javascript and then exporting it to PNG and SVG,** it is working fine.
[image]

There is another legends div that is designed using HTML, CSS, and JS.

[image]

```css
#diagramFilterStickyHeaderParentDiv{
    /*  border: 2px solid green; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#diagramFilterStickyHeader{
    /*  border: 2px solid red; */
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #7a7a7996;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    /*     justify-content: space-evenly; */
    align-items: center;
    width: 95%;
}
.diagramFilterCircleParentDiv{
/*  border: 1px solid black; */
/*     width: 10em; */
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
}

.circle{
    /*     background-color: blue; */
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.circleText{
    color: black;
}

.diagramFilterCircleParentDiv:hover{
    /*  background-color: #0D7E8A; */
    color: white;
    overflow: visible;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.circleText:hover{
    background-color: #0D7E8A;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="diagramFilterStickyHeaderParentDiv" style="display: flex;">
    <div id="diagramFilterStickyHeader">
        <div class="diagramFilterCircleParentDiv">
            <span class="circle" style="background-color:#191908"></span>
            <span class="circleText">Null</span>
        </div>
        <div class="diagramFilterCircleParentDiv">
            <span class="circle" style="background-color:#000000"></span>
            <span class="circleText">Core System</span>
        </div>
        <div class="diagramFilterCircleParentDiv">
            <span class="circle" style="background-color:#391804"></span>
            <span class="circleText">Support System</span>
        </div>
        <div class="diagramFilterCircleParentDiv">
            <span class="circle" style="background-color:#c6db6d"></span>
            <span class="circleText">Other</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want that legend div should be at the top of the diagram and then I can download it bot the diagram with the legend div(at the top of the diagram) as a PNG and SVG.

Here is the code that is used to download the mxgraph diagram as PNG and SVG

```
   function exportAsPNG(){
    var format = 'png';
    var bg = '#ffffff';
    var scale = 1;
    var b = 1;
    
    var imgExport = new mxImageExport();
    var bounds = graph2.getGraphBounds();
    var vs = graph2.view.scale;
    
    // New image export
    var xmlDoc = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
    var root = xmlDoc.createElement('output');
    xmlDoc.appendChild(root);
    
    // Renders graph2. Offset will be multiplied with state's scale when painting state.
    var xmlCanvas = new mxXmlCanvas2D(root);
    xmlCanvas.translate(Math.floor((b / scale - bounds.x) / vs)+30, Math.floor((b / scale - bounds.y) / vs));
    xmlCanvas.scale(scale / vs);
    
    imgExport.drawState(graph2.getView().getState(graph2.model.root), xmlCanvas);

    // Puts request data together
    var w = Math.ceil(bounds.width * scale / vs + 2 * b)+100;
    var h = Math.ceil(bounds.height * scale / vs + 2 * b)+50;
    var xml = mxUtils.getXml(root);
        
    if (bg != null)
    {
        bg = '&bg=' + bg;
    }
    
    new mxXmlRequest('Export', 'filename='+modelName+'.' + format + '&format=' + format +
        bg + '&w=' + w + '&h=' + h + '&xml=' + encodeURIComponent(xml)).
        simulate(document);
    $('#exportGraph').empty();
}
```

and for svg

```
function exportAsSVG() {
    var background = '#ffffff';
    var scale = 1;
    var border = 1;

    var imgExport = new mxImageExport();
    var bounds = graph2.getGraphBounds();
    var vs = graph2.view.scale;

    // Prepares SVG document that holds the output
    var svgDoc = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
    var root = (svgDoc.createElementNS != null) ?
        svgDoc.createElementNS(mxConstants.NS_SVG, 'svg') : svgDoc.createElement('svg');

    if (background != null) {
        if (root.style != null) {
            root.style.backgroundColor = background;
        }
        else {
            root.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:' + background);
        }
    }

    if (svgDoc.createElementNS == null) {
        root.setAttribute('xmlns', mxConstants.NS_SVG);
        root.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', mxConstants.NS_XLINK);
    }
    else {
        // KNOWN: Ignored in IE9-11, adds namespace for each image element instead. No workaround.
        root.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', mxConstants.NS_XLINK);
    }

    root.setAttribute('width', (Math.ceil(bounds.width * scale / vs) + 2 * border) + 100 + 'px');
    root.setAttribute('height', (Math.ceil(bounds.height * scale / vs) + 2 * border) + 50 + 'px');
    root.setAttribute('version', '1.1');

    // Adds group for anti-aliasing via transform
    var group = (svgDoc.createElementNS != null) ?
        svgDoc.createElementNS(mxConstants.NS_SVG, 'g') : svgDoc.createElement('g');
    group.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0.5,0.5)');
    root.appendChild(group);
    svgDoc.appendChild(root);

    // Renders graph2. Offset will be multiplied with state's scale when painting state.
    var svgCanvas = new mxSvgCanvas2D(group);
    svgCanvas.translate(Math.floor((border / scale - bounds.x) / vs) + 30, Math.floor((border / scale - bounds.y) / vs));
    svgCanvas.scale(scale / vs);

    // Displayed if a viewer does not support foreignObjects (which is needed to HTML output)
    svgCanvas.foAltText = '[Not supported by viewer]';
    imgExport.drawState(graph2.getView().getState(graph2.model.root), svgCanvas);

    var xml = encodeURIComponent(mxUtils.getXml(root));
    var xml1 = mxUtils.getXml(root);
    new mxXmlRequest('Echo', 'filename=' + modelName + '.svg&format=svg' + '&xml=' + xml).simulate(document);
    $('#exportGraph').empty();
}
```

Any help will be grateful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I read your source correctly the graph is drawn onto a (SVG|HTML)canvas using 2d canvas methods. You can not append HTML to this. Use canvas methods to draw the legend.

Comment: But how, can you give me a example code or can you modify my above provided function (exportAspng())

Comment: This would be outside the scope of an answer. I suggest you check the documentation for the [2D canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes).